# How to maintain focus in an input box after using mouse to select value from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input box which relies on a Google API to suggest city/state combinations based on what user types.  When user selects a Google suggested city/state combination from a dropdown list of possible options with a mouse (this issue doesn't exist if user makes his selection using up/down arrow keys), the input box for some reason loses focus.  How can we ensure that input box maintains focus after user selects the correct value from the Google dropdown using the mouse?  Here's my html code:

```
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input gp-gac="{ types: ['(cities)'],  componentRestrictions: { country: 'US' }}" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="home_ctrl.location"
                        gp-components="{ locality: 'long_name', administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name' }"
                        gp-callback="home_ctrl.gpSearchCb(result, place)"
                        vs-city="home_ctrl.city"
                        vs-state="home_ctrl.state"
                        placeholder="City, State"
                        id="txtCity">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

I tried to include an onclick event inside the input tag

```
onclick = "putFocus()"
```

which references the following function in my javascript code:

```
function putFocus(){
  document.getElementByd("txtCity").focus()
}
```

But that didn't seem to do the trick either.  Appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a custom *CSS class* with how you want the input to be displayed to the user when "focused" and add it to your input when user clicks. `.focus` is not going to do the trick because when an input is in focus state it is "selected", meaning that the cursor is inside the input element.

Try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

  .focused{
    border-style: solid, 10px;
    border-color: blue;
  }

</style>


<body>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onClick="myFunction()">

<script>

  function myFunction() {
      myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
      myInput.classList.add("focused");
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your response.  I'm not concerned about the appearance of the input box or its contents when in focus.  My problem is that the input box loses focus (nothing on the page is in focus) as soon as user selects a value from the dropdown using a mouse in particular.  This issue doesn't exist if user uses up/down arrow keys to make his selection.

Comment: I thought you wanted focus just for displaying purposes. If you want it to stay focused try adding `onfocusout = "myFunction()"` instead of `onclick = "myFunction()"`

Comment: That didn't do the trick either.  As soon as user clicks the mouse to select a value from the list of suggested locations that google maps API presents, a blur event seems to occur such that no element on the page is in focus any longer.  Could this have something to do with how google maps API works?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out.  All I had to do was add the following line to the end of the gpSearchCb function in the homeController.js file:

```
$('#txtCity').focus()
```

and that maintains focus in the correct input field after making selection with a mouse.